# Mask any 15-digit or 16-digit credit card number in a string by replacing with X's except for the last 4 digits. Complex Regex puzzle in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am running into what I think is a difficult Regex problem/puzzle in C#/.NET 4.7

I have been tasked to mask any **15-digit** or **16-digit** credit card number in a string, if there is one present.  There may also be spaces in between the digits of the credit card number.  Here are some examples that hopefully get the point across:

- `"CC# 123456789012345"` becomes `"CC# XXXXXXXXXXX2345"` (`15`-digit example)
- `"Credit Card 123456 7890 123456"` becomes `"Credit Card XXXXXXXXXXXX3456"` (`16`-digit example with random spaces)
- `"Text 1234 5678 9012 3456 Text"` becomes `"Text XXXXXXXXXXXX3456 Text"`
- `"Something 123 456 789 012 345"` becomes `"Something XXXXXXXXXXX2345"`

Basically, the **last 4** of the credit card *should always be present*, and the *rest* of the digits are to be masked with `X`'s.  So for `15`-digit cases, there should be `11` `X`'s before the `4` digits, and for `16`-digit case, there should be `12` `X`'s before the last `4` digits.

** The idea is that if a user enters a credit card number in an open text field, we mask it before storing in the db. My one respite is that they may not put any special characters except for `spaces` in the string.  The string is always a maximum of `40` characters long.**

This is proving to be a decently difficult regex problem to figure out (or maybe I shouldn't use regex at all?...).  Thus I have been using *ChatGPT* to create some regular expressions, and gotten close, but none that actually provided me with the correct output.  The closest I have gotten is roughly the following:

```
private static string MaskCreditCardNumber(string input) 
{
  string pattern = @"\b(?:\d[ -]*?){11,15}(?=\d{4}\b)";

  string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => 
      new string('X', match.Length - 4) + 
      match.Value.Substring(match.Length - 4));

  return output;
}
```

This seems like it's masking all but the last `8` digits for most of my test cases, but that's *not exactly* what I want obviously, since I want the last `4`.

Tried for about 8 hours on ChatGPT creating various different `Regex`, as well as trying my own.  Still could not solve this replacement algorithm.  Looking for help on creating this regex replacement algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the task in two steps:

1. With a help of *regular expression* obtain *possible match*: digits mixed with spaces
2. Count digits, and if you get exactly `15` or `16` format this *true match* into the requred representation

For instance we can use `[0-9][0-9 ]{13,}[0-9]` pattern

```
[0-9]       - digit in 0..9 range
[0-9 ]{13,} - at least 13 digits or spaces
[0-9]       - digit in 0..9 range
```

and the code below:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string MaskCreditCardNumber(string text) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    return text;

  return Regex.Replace(text, "[0-9][0-9 ]{13,}[0-9]", match => {
    string digits = string.Concat(match.Value
      .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)));

    return digits.Length == 16 || digits.Length == 15
      ? new string('X', digits.Length - 4) + digits.Substring(digits.Length - 4)
      : match.Value;
  });
}
```

Demo:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "CC# 123456789012345",
  "Credit Card 123456 7890 123456",
  "Text 1234 5678 9012 3456 Text",
  "Something 123 456 789 012 3456",
  "Not a card (too long): 12345689123456789123",
  "Just a value 123",
};

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,45} => {MaskCreditCardNumber(test)}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
                          CC# 123456789012345 => CC# XXXXXXXXXXX2345
               Credit Card 123456 7890 123456 => Credit Card XXXXXXXXXXXX3456
                Text 1234 5678 9012 3456 Text => Text XXXXXXXXXXXX3456 Text
               Something 123 456 789 012 3456 => Something XXXXXXXXXXXX3456
  Not a card (too long): 12345689123456789123 => Not a card (too long): 12345689123456789123
                             Just a value 123 => Just a value 123
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GWZHdo) yourself

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will need some time to review but this looks very helpful.  I'll comment back once I implement some of these ideas.

Comment: I cannot upvote due to SO's dumb policy but this regex is looking like it has been extremely helpful in fixing some bugs for us.  We had a few other fields that were "close" but not always working in all cases for masking out CC numbers.

Comment: Dmitry, I'm a junior-intermediate level developer who is looking to level up my skills to get to the point where you're at.  What would you recommend for me to do at this point?  I feel like I have plateaued to some level as I'm not getting better much more rapidly at this point.  I have been coding almost daily since I was about 17 and I am 30 now.  I have a CS engineering degree as well.  I would like to continue growing and learning but not sure what to do.  Should I just do a ton of LeetCode and HackerRank type problems (C#, Javascript SQL, Regex, etc)?  Maybe read system-design books?

Comment: @CheckpointSoftworks: I think the trick is in developing good habits: do not tolerate any ignorance - if you feel you have difficulties with regex, why not spend an hour reading https://www.regular-expressions.info/ while fiddling at https://regex101.com/ to improve understanding? Solving LeetCode problems is a good habit as well - just 15 minutes a day (no more than 1 or 2 problems) and you'll get 500 at the end of the year with good algorithms and data structures understanding. I read system-design books while commuting: it's so boring to spend an hour in a bus from Kilcolgan to Galway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use thir regex to find 15 or 16 credit card numbers:

```
(?<!\d *)\d(?: *\d *){13,14}\d(?! *\d)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/UnxpFm/1

Aslo you might need to use checksum verification (e.g. [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)) to check if those digits form a credit card number.

and the code:

```
string Sanitize(string input) =>
    Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\d.*)\d(?: *\d *){13,14}\d(?! *\d)", m =>
    {
        var digitsOnly = m.Value.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        var numberOfSanitizedDigits = m.Value.Count(char.IsDigit) - 4;

        return new string('X', numberOfSanitizedDigits) + digitsOnly[^4..];
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will need some time to implement these ideas but it seems like this could also be on the right track.  I cannot upvote due to SO's dumb policy.